# chrome div content not getting update on scroll

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-chrome, html

I have a site, on which I have been implementing ajax loading of the site's pages into a div, as replacement for the use of an iframe.  All is working well, except that chrome won't properly render the scrolling content inside the div. chrome's display for the lower portion of the div will not refresh on scroll and remains static (the video is not being rerendered) while the rest of the content moves as would be expected with the scroll action. The only way to make everything display normally is to manually resize the browser window, forcing chrome to refresh its display for the entire page. I looked a little closer and chrome prohibits javascript window resizing on any window that is not window.open'd, my first inclination as a fix, so that's out. so how does this get fixed? Is there a better `overflow:` setting?

here is the website:

http://tablapusher.com

any help is greatly appreciated, as:

```
window.resizeTo(theWidth+1,theHeight+1)
```

does not work. thanks!

Comment: ok, i seem to be making a little headway by adjusting the pixel size of the div, now to just make it fire at the right time... possibly in the ajax function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the pixel size of the div via discretionary setTimeout interval after the 200 response in ajax did the trick... the pixel needs to change every page click, tho... bottom: 1px > 0px > 1px > etc. hope this helps anyone with the same issue.